# mostrar pagina local desde otra app en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un proyecto html dentro de la carpeta assets, puedo mostrar la pagina desde un webview, pero el objecto es poder mostrar esa pagina también desde otro navegador instalado en el dispositivos, por ejemplo "http://localhost:56566" en ves de file:///android_asset/index.html

algo como esto es a donde quiero llegar.
[image: ejemplo de lo que quiero]

Comment: Tendrias que usar sockets y servir tu contenido por el puerto que desees como servidor web.

Comment: dime eso se puede hacer desde android tambie. si me entendiste cierto, puedes ver la imagen que mostre.

Comment: Si si la vi y si se puede hacer inclusive existe una apliación de android que monta un servidor web con php y todo.

Comment: Lo que tu servidor me imagino que tendria que ser un servicio corriendo en background.

Comment: la verdad lo único que quiero mostrar es una pagina web que esta dentro de la carpeta assent de mi poryecto

Comment: la pagina tiene css, js, imagenes, es una sola pagina o tiene varias???

Comment: es solo una pagina, y pues claro que tiene css, js y una imagen, pero es solo una. de igual manera el objectivo es mostrar almenos un mensaje y una imagen.

Comment: la pagina es estatica??

Comment: si , la pagina solo se muestra y nada mas, no tiene interacción, es solo un mensaje y nada mas

Comment: el usuario tendria ke abrirla manual o la app lo hace

Comment: tengo el servicio que que hace que la app, lo haga ella sólita, pero no tengo la manera de poder mostrar la pagina desde un navegador externo, osea dentro de la app con un webview no hay problema, pero necesito que si el usuario quiere meter esa misma pagina desde la barra de navegacion, muestre el mismo resultado que en el webview.

Comment: @NelsonRedondoBarros desde la barra de navegación te refieres al navegador Chrome, un navegador externo a la aplicación?

Comment: si, lo que me gustaria en si por el momento es poder servir una pagina web estatica local en mi dispositivo, osea que esa pagina solo podra ser asedida desde un nabegador web,ya sea googlechrome, firefox u otro, pero atraves de la siguiente url = "http://localhost:8181", ejemplo claro

Comment: Puedes usar esta librería https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, muchas gracias creo que esa información me es muy util

Comment: Espero que resuelvas, en especifico tienes que usar la webserver y el core

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, muchas gracias, estaba buscando correctamente eso. sin duda eres el mejor

Comment: jajaja No hay de que